# Solve a Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $p(x)<0$ for all real numbers and y(x) is a solution of the DE $$y'+p(x)y=0$$ that is not identically zero. I need to prove that y can cross the x axis at most once.

I don't understand the answer below, any other help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rough idea: between two consecutive zeroes of $y$, $y'$ must vanish. But $y'=-p(x)y(x)$, which has constant sign between consecutives zeroes of $y$.

Comment: @ siminore how do I know that Y has a zero or 2 zeros as you claim?

Comment: Oh, you do not know. But you asked to prove the existence of at most one zero. I gave you a hint to prove that two zeroes are impossible, hence you can have either no zero or one zero.

Comment: @ siminore thank you for responding. You are saying that between consecutive zeros of y, y'=0  in all of the interval, or just at the zeros? Please be patient with me.

Comment: @ siminore, correct me if I'm wrong, but I was thinking that in between the two zeros there is an extremum and there y'=0 but our DE says that y' cannot be zero in between zeros. Is this right?

Comment: By Rolle's theorem, $f(a)=f(b)=0$ implies the existence of a critical point between $a$ and $b$. Then you can derive a contradiction with the DE.